# Prove that $\{n\phi^{-1}\}$, divides largest gap of $\{\phi^{-1}\},..., \{(n-1)\phi^{-1}\}$ as ratio of $\phi$, where $\phi$ is the golden ratio

Tags: sequences-and-series

Prove that $\{n\phi^{-1}\}$, divides largest gap of $\{\phi^{-1}\},..., \{(n-1)\phi^{-1}\}$ as ratio of $\phi$, where $\phi$ is the golden ratio

Comment: You type math too fast. A few words in human language would help a great deal. Like, _"here I'm dividing the (largest?) gap by the left (or right?) of the two parts into which it is split, and expect (why?) to get $\varphi$"_.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Edited. Does that help?

Comment: Yes, somewhat. So my guesswork was mostly right. You are dividing the largest gap by the left of the two parts into which it is split, and expect to get $\varphi$. Why? Why use this part and not the other, to begin with?

Comment: I'm stupid. I should looking at $\frac{|\{\phi^{-1}\} - \{2\phi^{-1}\}|}{\{2\phi^{-1}\}}$

Comment: Going to remove the me goofing-up bit..thanks for your help :)